# Setting Dynamic ng-model everytime a directive is called

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that consists of the following:

everytime a button is clicked, a new form is appended to the form.

Problem: I need to have a different ng-model for each new form being appended.
After almost banging my head against the wall for a whole day I'm still clueless

nb: dynamical ng-model using ng-repeat is not possible as i only need to append 1 template at a time

here's the code : plunkr version : https://plnkr.co/edit/4zjo8xRHD5gMm5kU77Tv?p=info

```
    app.directive("addIsmb", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function () {
                var toAppend = $compile("<i-smb></i-smb>")(scope)
                $(".iSMBHolder").append(toAppend);
                $(".countISMB").each(function(){
                    var self = $(this);
                    var index = self.parent().index();
                    scope.ctrl.iIndex = index+1;
                })
              console.log(scope.ctrl.iIndex)  
            })
        }
    }
})
```

my directive for the template

```
app.directive("isbm", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E", 
    templateURL: "app/location of my template",
    replace: false
  }
})
```

the controller : I attempt to create an array that will return an object inside a for loop so that I could use every object being returned as a ng-model but it failed.

```
app.controller("separated.inputs", ["C2CData", "channelData", function (C2CData, channelData) {
  self.iList = new Array(10);

    for (i = 0; i < self.iList.length; i++){
        self.iList[i] = {}
    };

}])
```

the template where I need to have dynamic ng-model

```
<div md-whiteframe="6" layout="column" class="iSMB animated fadeInUp countISMB ncInputSettings" get-idex>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" class="notToBeFolded">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" id="ncInputTitle">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="icons/ncInputTitleSettings.svg" class="md-36"></md-icon>
            <md-content>{{ctrl.iList[ctrl.iIndex.name]}}</md-content>
        </div>
        <md-button class="md-primary ncDeleteSMBS" delete-ismb>CANCEL</md-button>
    </div>
    <div class="toBeFolded">
        <div layout="row" class="ncInputRow">
            <div flex="40" class="ncBorderMe" layout-align="start center" layout="row" layout-padding>
                <md-content class="md-heading">Name</md-content>
            </div>
            <div flex layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" layout-padding>
                <input placeholder="Pick a Name" disabled class="ncInputListInput" ng-model="ctrl.iList[ctrl.iIndex.name]"/>
                <md-button edit-field aria-label="Chose a name" class="ncMdButton">
                    <md-icon class="material-icon ncIconNoMargin">edit</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a Javascript expression within the `ng-model` like most Angular directives. Why don't you try this:

```
<input placeholder="Pick a Name" disabled class="ncInputListInput" ng-model="scopeFunction($index)"/>
```

And then within your controller:

```
$scope.scopeFunction = function(index) {
  return $scope.models[index+1]; //Or something of that sort
}
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work could you please be more specific in your code ?